# How can I restrict the range of a plot within a slope field?

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a way to restrict the range of the plotted function so that I don't have to enter the domain manually? I have tried clipping, but that also clips the axis labels and the description above the slope field.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, declare function={f(\x,\y)=(\x)+3*(\y)/(\x);}] 
\def\xmax{5} \def\xmin{-5} 
\def\ymax{5} \def\ymin{-5} 
\def\nx{10} 
\def\ny{10} 

\pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\nx} 
\foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}{
\ifnum\i=5 \else 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}
\draw[blue,thick, shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}] 
(0,0)--($(0,0)!4mm!(.1,.1*\yprime)$);
\fi
} 

\def\yo{0.25926}
\draw[red, thick, samples=100] plot[domain=\xmin:\xmax, yrange=\ymin:\ymax] (\x,{-1*(\x)^2-(\yo)*(\x)^3}); 

\draw[->] (\xmin-.5,0)--(\xmax+.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,\ymin-.5)--(0,\ymax+.5) node[above left] {$y$};
\draw (current bounding box.north) node[above]
{Slope field of $y'=x+\dfrac{3y}{x}$.}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Clipping works if you do it within a scope. Then only the stuff in the scope will be clipped.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, declare function={f(\x,\y)=(\x)+3*(\y)/(\x);}] 
\def\xmax{5} \def\xmin{-5} 
\def\ymax{5} \def\ymin{-5} 
\def\nx{10} 
\def\ny{10} 

\pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\nx} 
\foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}{
\ifnum\i=5 \else 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}
\draw[blue,thick, shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}] 
(0,0)--($(0,0)!4mm!(.1,.1*\yprime)$);
\fi
} 
\begin{scope}
\clip (\xmin,\ymin-0.5) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
\def\yo{0.25926}
\draw[red, thick, samples=100] plot[domain=\xmin:\xmax] (\x,{-1*(\x)^2-(\yo)*(\x)^3}); 
\end{scope}
\draw[->] (\xmin-.5,0)--(\xmax+.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,\ymin-.5)--(0,\ymax+.5) node[above left] {$y$};
\draw (current bounding box.north) node[above]
{Slope field of $y'=x+\dfrac{3y}{x}$.}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that you were loading but not using `pgfplots`. You could use is and produce a quiver plot. Then clipping would be automatic.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you so much!